# How to add custom spring cloud gateway filter in Java config?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I've created a custom filter in Spring Cloud Gateway by extending the class with "LoggingGlobalPreFilter"

I have the following routes.

```
return builder.routes().route(r -> r.path("/first/**").uri("http://localhost:8222"))
        .route(r -> r.path("/seconf/**").uri("http://localhost:8333")).build();
```

Not sure how to add custom filter there. All the articles on the internet are talking about configuring filters in .yml file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
   
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.